# How can I solve the variable is not defined error in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, tweepy, undefined-variable

Error in this statement that auth is not defined after i already defined it.
You can check the code.

```
import tweepy

consumer_key = 'xxx'
consumer_secret = 'xxx'
callback_url = 'ooo'
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret, callback_url)
redirect_url = auth.get_Authorization_url()
print(auth)
```

Note: this code work fine in Pycharm environment but it doesn't work on jupyter notebook giving me error variable auth is not defined

Comment: Restart your kernel and run the cell again